# Wave dynamic paint is not circular

Tags: modeling, modifiers, dynamic-paint, simulation-nodes

I don't undestand why the ripples produced by the cone, are somewhat squared.

Any idea on how to get perfectly circular ripples ?

[image: view1]

[image: view topology]

[image: top view]

Here is the blend file [ripple_test](https://we.tl/t-CDvX3m8GCH)

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: Maybe you should create a different topology like concentric circles

Comment: I just posted the blend file